# The post from Chatter group in Salesforce not properly displayed

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, javascript-remoting, chatter-feed

I am using javascript remoting to get the chatterfeed details and putting it in the visualforce component and show it using Handlebar Moustache . Below is the part of that component

{{#if elements.length}}
      
      {{#each elements}}
      
          
            
              
            
          
          
            {{actor.name}}
             
                {{#each body.messageSegments}}
                {{#isTextSegment type}}
                  **{{text}}**
                {{/isTextSegment}}
                {{#isMentionSegment type}}
                  {{record.displayName}}
                {{/isMentionSegment}}
              {{/each}}

If someone posts in the chatter group, its displayed like this
"This is just for a test. 1. Paragraph 1 2. Paragraph 2 3. Paragraph 3"

instead of this

This is just for a test.
1. Paragraph 1
2. Paragraph 2
3. Paragraph 3

Is there anyway I can show it in the exact format it was posted ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't without an insane amount of extra work. Javascript remoting ONLY returns the value from the method. You'll need to take that value and reformat it from scratch on your own.

Visualforce will display it exactly as it should be displayed using built in Visualforce tags.

```
<apex:outputField />
<chatter:feed />
```

[chatter:feed reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm)

One of the things developers have a hard time realizing is that Salesforce does most of the work for you if you let it. If you can't move past all the libraries and tools you've grown accustom to using in normal web development, you're going to have a hard time.

If you REALLY want to do it from scratch, look into SLDS (Salesforce Lightning Design System) assuming you're using lightning. If you're using Classic, better start skimming through the default stylesheets and get ready to spend hours in the chrome developer console learning what classes to use and what HTML tags to replicate. Salesforce uses very specific CSS so you'll have to make sure your elements are children of the correct elements/classes in order to get something even remotely close.

The final option is to style it yourself and give up on the idea of making it look like it was when it was entered. This is the middle ground between the two solutions and will take the least amount of work as it's likely what you're used to doing. You'll parse the results returned by the remote method and format yourself.

Comment: Just what I was afraid of..Anyway, thanks for the info Toby.. I have this cookbook on "chatter to apex-Displaying a feed" which is displayed  in Visualforce tags..   
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/cookbookRecipeSource?id=a1V30000000CS0jEAG  

Can't I just take the essentials from here just for the post to be displayed in proper format somethin similiar like

 <apex:outputtext value="{!feedItemInfo.formattedText}" escape="false">

 and rest all elements in Handlebar moustache template? Will that help ?

Comment: I don't know enough about Handlebar to say yes or no. Visualforce tags only work in Visualforce pages. If you try to put the tag outside of a VF page (like a static resource) and than include it into the page it wont work. Theoretically if you define the template within the VF page... maybe? But that seems like the opposite of how a template should be used.